# CSS multiple background-images and "contain"

Tags: html, css

Good day!
I don´t know if it´s even possible, but I´m looking for a way to place two or more background-images underneath each other in one div. The images should resize automagically with the "background-size: contain;" tag. Is there a way to do this? I´ve already tried the following:

```css
background-image: url('../img/bild.jpg'), url('../img/bild2.jpg');
background-size: contain contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

But it didn´t worked...

Greets,
Johnny

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `,` between `contain`

```
background-image: url('../img/bild.jpg'), url('../img/bild2.jpg');
background-size: contain, contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

you can set any set of values for multiple background each separated by `,`. But values for one background are separated by whitespace. Example: difference can be seen in position:

```
background-position: ??px ??px, ??px ??px;
                     ^^^^ ^^^^  ^^^^ ^^^^
       position for:  image 1    image 2
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this case, image2 is positioned on top of image1, and not underneath :-/ Because the height (because of "contain") and the images itself are variable, I can´t set a "background-position: 0px ???px;"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The problem I have is following: I can´t set the exact background-position for every image, because 
1. the images are different on every page aaand 
2. because of the automatic resizing ("contain"-attrib.) the height depends on the viewport-size. So a hardcoded pixel value isn´t an option :-/ 
The images should just be placed underneath each other...

Answer (score 0):

hi even you can try this same result using the shorthand method that the only use of background property

you can try this

```css
background: url('../img/bild.jpg'), url('../img/bild2.jpg') no-repeat / contain;
```

Comment: Doesn´t work :-/ Firefox ignores the whole declaration.

Comment: @JohnnyW. is it working in chrome.? hey hey just apply updated one because i misplaced the **background-image** instead of only using **background**  as updated